# A proof about martingales and variance

Tags: limits, probability-theory, expectation, martingales

We consider a martingale $(S_n)$ with $\mathbb E(S_n^2)<K<\infty$. Suppose that $\mathrm{ Var}(S_n)\rightarrow0$.

Prove that $S=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}S_n$ exists and is constant a.s.

I don't know how to start here.

One thing we  know is that $\mathrm{ Var} (S_n)=\mathbb E(S_n^2)-\mathbb E(S_n)^2$, so for every $\epsilon<0$, we have $\mathbb E(S_n^2)\leq\mathbb E(S_n)^2+\epsilon$. But where should I use the martingale property?

Comment: $S=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}S_n=E(S)$

Comment: Okay, this follows by the martingale property, I guess. But how can we show the existence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The existence of the limit $S$ follows from the martingale convergence theorem (because the expectation of $|S_n|$ is uniformly bounded), see for instance Durrett's book *Probability: Theory and Examples* page 235.

It remains to show that the limit is almost surely constant. To this aim, notice that $\mathbb E(S_n)\to \mathbb E(S)$ and apply Fatou's lemma to the sequence $\left((S_n-\mathbb E(S_n))^2\right)_{ n\geqslant 1} $.

Comment: thanks. I can't find the theorem in the book. http://www.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE4_1.pdf I still try to find it. Maybe you can take a look too?:) Edit: Found it! Its Theorem 5.2.8

Comment: I am still struggling to understand this. Some questions: 1) We can use the martingale convergence theorem because $\mathbb E(S_n^2)<\infty$ imsplies $\mathbb E(S_n^+)$? Which is needed for the theorem (see durrett). 2) Should I consider $\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mathbb E((S_n-\mathbb E(S_n))^2)$ and apply fatous lemma? 3)Where we use that $Var(S_n)\rightarrow 0$? Maybe we will need this in question 2)? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) and 3) The fact that $Var(S_n)\to 0$ gives that $\liminf_n\mathbb E(S_n-\mathbb E(S_n))^2=0$ and the application of Fatou's lemma gives that the variance of $S$ is $0$.

Comment: But how we know then that $S$ is an almost sure constant function i.e. $S(x)=c \in \mathbb R$ for almost all $x$. Or do I misunderstand something?

Comment: If the variance of a random variable is $0$, then this random variable is almost surely constant.

Comment: Doesn't fatous lemma only work for positive random variables? Of course we can split S into its positive and negative part, but I guess this would only work if the variance would be linear. This is true if $S^+$ and $S^-$ are independent. Is this the case?

Comment: It does work for the sequence I suggest because $(S_n-\mathbb E(S_n))^2$ is non-negative.